# Cual es la mejor forma de convertir un double a string para colocarlo en un textbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Buenas tengo una consulta, deseo convertir en visual studio 2017 un dato double para colocarlo en un campo textbox, pero no encuentro la forma correcta de realizarlo.
Cual seria la mejor forma de hacerlo, gracias

Comment: Eso depende del lenguaje de programación y no del IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Si usas c#:

```
Double total; 
Textbox1.Text = total.toString();
```